# Microsoft Graph API reports : error 404 UnknownTenantId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When trying to retrieve data from a v1.0 report endpoint on a demo tenant, for example:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserCounts(period='D7')`

I get this strange result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownTenantId",
        "message": "We do not recognize this tenant ID 3d64a....7279c0. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7b7b8....8029b",
            "date": "2018-04-30T09:32:46"
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of an HTTP 302 redirection to get the CSV report results (according to [the doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getoffice365activeusercounts)).

I'm trying from Graph API Explorer, authenticated as tenant admin account, this has worked as expected before tenant expiration + extension (a few hours ago)

I will try in a few hours again, tomorrow etc. (I'll write the results here) because this error looks to be related to tenant expiration (or else, what is happening?)...

Comment: This looks similar to what happens if you attempt to hit a tenant immediately after provisioning it. It takes a little time for the tenant id to propagate across all the instances. Most likely your tenant was deactivated and needs to go through the same process.